# Find the volume under the parametric surface

Tags: integration, volume, parametric

I have a surface defined in $(x,y,z)$ by
$$(a(t-\sin(t)),a(1-\cos(t))\cos(\theta),a(1-\cos(t))\sin(\theta))$$ Where  both $\theta$ and $ t$ varies between $[0,2\pi]$ how can I find the volume bounded by this surface? I started from the equations 
$$x(t)=a(t-\sin(t))\qquad y(t)=a(1-\cos(t)).$$

Answer (score 0):

The surface is obtained by revolving the plane curve
$$(x(t),y(t))=a(t-\sin(t), 1−\cos(t))\quad t\in [0,2\pi],$$
which is a [Cycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid#Equations) in parametric form, around the $x$-axis.

In order to compute the volume see [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution#Parametric_form):
$$V=\pi\int_0^{2\pi} y(t)^2 x'(t)dt=a^3\pi\int_0^{2\pi} (1−\cos(t))^2
\cdot(1-\cos(t)) dt.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Actually I initially worked on that integral but my teacher told me it was wrong, nonetheless it makes sense to me, thank you I can take it from there

Comment: @jrgs What was wrong exactly? Have you the answer of this exercise?

Comment: I dont have the answer.
My teacher reply was that I wasnt able to integrate in respect to $t$ because the parameters are in a different dimension

Comment: @Jrgs I'am sorry, I don't understand your teacher's comment. Try the above integral, the final result should be $5\pi^2a^3$. See also here: http://www.nabla.hr/FU-DefIntegralAppl4.htm

Comment: @Jrgs Any news about your problem?